# Font Showing Up as Bold

Tags: html, css

For some reason, the text underneath the "Support Us" section is all in bold.  I've tried forcing the font-style to normal, but it remains bold.  The JSFiddle looks kind of messy, but if you scroll to the right, you can see my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/4bQjs/

Here is the HTML Code for that section:

```
<div id="rightcolumn">
<div id="supportus">

<div class="TitleBG">
    <h5>SUPPORT US</h5>
    </div>

<div style="float: left;margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;outline:#747474 solid thin;">
    <img src="images/marathon.jpg" width="500" height="265" />
</div>

<div style="float:left; text-align: left">


The Baltimore Running Festival

<br></br>

One of the more popular races of the Baltimore Running Festival is the Team Relay. Running the same course as the marathoners, 
the Team Relay consists of FOUR participants per team with each runner selecting a portion of the marathon course to run. 

<br></br>

Our Cause

<br></br>

We are participating in our first ever team relay to raise money to support our research.  With your help, we can raise money
to continue our fight against Lyme disease and Post-treatment Lyme disease syndrome.

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#supportus {
  min-height: 645px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  outline:#e8e8e8 solid thin;
  font-family:"Helvetica",Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: That code example is horrible.

Comment: <br></br>?? what the heck

Comment: What's wrong with the <br>...isn't that just a line break?  And why is the code example horrible...trying to learn, advice is appreciated!

Comment: `<br>` is a self-enclosing tag, meaning that you don't need to specify an ending. In XHTML you can do `<br/>` and in HTML `<br>` will suffice. The code is horrible because it is a mess, and also because it includes many deprecated tags which are not semantic, including `<font>` (which should have been dead in the 90s) and, to a certain extent, even `<b>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a random `<b>` tag floating around that is enclosing your `#rightcolumn`. It's right here:

`<b> <p>To find out more about these findings go to our description and listing`

I believe the problem is that you wrapped a `p` with a `b` and never closed the paragraph. Double check your HTML and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your #rightcolumn is nested in a `<b>` tag